# Error in string.join while creating a multi dimensional array

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created a multi-dimensional array:

```
 string[,] array_questions = new string[dt.Rows.Count, dt.Columns.Count]; 
    for (i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
   {
   for (j = 0; j < dt.Columns.Count; j++)
   {
       array_questions[i, j] = dt.Rows[i][j].ToString();
       //Response.Write(array_questions[i, j]);
  }
 //  Response.Write(Environment.NewLine);
 //Response.Write("\n");
  }
foreach (string number in array_questions)
    {
        //Response.Write(number + " ");
        //Response.Write(Environment.NewLine);
        Response.Write(string.Join(", ", number) + Environment.NewLine);         
    }
```

but it shows an error like : Error  1   The best overloaded method match for 'string.Join(string, string[])' has some invalid arguments.. Please help

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a for loop to join the string.

```
string.Join(", ", array_questions)
```

Replace the code

```
foreach (string number in array_questions)
{
    //Response.Write(number + " ");
    //Response.Write(Environment.NewLine);
    Response.Write(string.Join(", ", number) + Environment.NewLine);         
}
```

with

```
Response.Write(string.Join(", ", array_questions) + Environment.NewLine);
```

Comment: @PSL : then what else should i do to get array elements row wise ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to flatten your array to use `string.Join`. It takes the separator and a single dimensional array, so you may proabably need to do something like this. But not sure what you are trying to achieve here. You are trying to call `string.Join(string, string[])` as `string.Join(string, string)`

Try something like this:

```
        var sdArray= new List<string>();
        for (var i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++) //Get the length of first Dimension
        {
            for (var j = 0; j < dt.Columns.Count; j++) //Get the length of second Dimension
            {
                sdArray.Add(array_questions[i, j]);
            }
        }

       ///
        Response.Write(string.Join(", ", sdArray) + Environment.NewLine);
```

Using Linq you can flatten this in a better way.

Something like this

```
  string joinedSetOfQns= string.Join(",", 
       Enumerable.Range(0, dt.Rows.Count)
        .SelectMany(i => Enumerable.Range(0, dt.Columns.Count)
        .Select(j => array_questions[i, j])));    

               Response.Write(joinedSetOfQns + Environment.NewLine);
```

This is the defenision for [string.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx)

```
public static string Join(
    string separator,
    params string[] value  /// <-- Takes single Dimensional Array not a string.
)
```

#### Update: Since you need to join Rowwise

```
        for (var i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            var result = new List<string>();
            for (var j = 0; j < dt.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                result.Add(array_questions[i, j]);
            }
           Response.Write(string.Join(", ", result) + Environment.NewLine);
        }
```

Comment: I do like as you suggested. but the same error remains unchanged

Comment: yes i have compiled it . but shows ,Error 2 Argument '2': cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' to 'string[]'

Comment: @user2431727 which version of dotnet? anyways do `Response.Write(string.Join(", ", result.ToArray()) + Environment.NewLine);`

Comment: oops... :( the output is:  , , , , , , , , , ,   visual studio3.5